# Replacing window frame without replacing window?

Tags: windows

I was talking to someone and he mentioned that you could remove a window, replace the sill/frame, then put the old window back in....to me, that doesn't make sense at all, as the old window has caused the damage to the frame/sill. Has anyone heard of this being done?

Comment: It primarily depends if it is a build window or a replacement window but at the same time, its not that important. You can certainly do it; your point is accurate, your window may be damaged as well (but it may be perfectly fine), so if the window is perfectly fine; it would be foolish not to re-use it.

Comment: I believe they are talking more about the frame work and trim around the window. If the window frame itself is rotted out it would be a massive amount of work to save it but it could be done.